# How to update to newest cobol

Tags: cobol

How can I install the newest
cobol
language
version on my win 10 computer

I want to do programming like this

```
Identification Division.
    Program-ID. HALLOPGM.
    Procedure Division.
        Display "Hallo Welt!".
        STOP RUN.
```

Comment: You can download [GnuCOBOL](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnucobol/).

Comment: That's no programming question but asking for software. Therefore I suggest to delete / close/ move it. That's aside Gilbert is correct, the easiest way is to get a GnuCOBOL binary package (found on Arnold Trembley's website), then compile with 'cobc -free HALLOPGM.cob).

Comment: Fair warning: GnuCOBOL does not support OO COBOL yet, if you need that you may want to try finding a test version of Fujitsu Netcobol, but that's not free software.

Comment: ping about closing this question and possibly bring it to another SE site

Answer (score 0):

You can install [GNUCobol](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnucobol/) on your computer. It is a free version of COBOL.